# Безопасность программного обеспечения на PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql

У меня есть веб-сайт и программа(python).
Мне нужно подключить к программе базу данных веб-сайта!
Правильно ли будет с точки зрения безопасности, писать в коде программы?:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='user',
    password='password',
    host='host',
    database='database')

cur = conn.cursor()
```

Смогут ли 'взломщики' узнать ip,user,password....?

Comment: Если вы предоставите им какой-либо способ подсмотреть ip,user,password — узнают.

Comment: я имею ввиду, если я укажу данные подключения к базе-данных в коде программы, а после скомпилирую в exe. Смогут ли они увидеть как либо данные?

Comment: Если вы предоставите им exe-файл — раскомпилируют и прочитают.

Comment: А как тогда мне безопасно провести подключение к базе-данных веб-сайта?

Comment: Подключайтесь из места, которое контролируете только вы, например с купленного вами сервера. А программа пусть подключается к вашему серверу и пусть сервер предоставляет программе ограниченные возможности — ровно те, которые необходимы для работы программы. Также можно например потребовать обязательную регистрацию и не разрешать пользоваться программой до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт логин-пароль и сервер не подтвердит, что эти логин-пароль верны. По такой схеме работают все веб-сайты в интернете (в случае веб-сайтов такой программой является браузер, а веб-сайт находится на сервере)